# Jquery Iteration

Tags: jquery

I have coded the following which I had hoped would iterate through and display (with delays) a series of elements.  If fact it does different things in IE and FireFox but neither what I wanted!

Bill H

===========================================================================================

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#ulId').children().each(
    function(){  
        //access to form element via $(this)
                $('#dis').hide(2000).text($(this).text()).show(2000);
    });
});
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id='ulId'> 
  <li><span class='a'>Some Text1</span><img src="http://www.old-picture.com/europe/pictures/Heisterbach-ruins.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><span class='a'>Some Text2</span><img src="http://www.theodora.com/wfb/photos/syria/roman_ruins_palmyra_syria_photo_gov.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><span class='a'>Some Text3</span><img src="http://www.cosmos.com/Common/Images/Destinations/delphi-ruins.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
<div id='dis' style='background-color: red; color: white'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post the actual code as it is, and format it with the `{}` button in the editor. What you have now is unreadable. Also, please describe better what _is_ happening and what you _want_ to happen.

Comment: yes... please be more clear with what you want to happen...

Answer (score 0):

check this out, it is for XML, but i think it will work for XHTML too, I had the same issue and this helped me, you are facing this but because IE object structure is a bit diff from the rest.

```
    var parseXml;
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parseXml = function (xmlStr) {
            return (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
        };
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new
window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
        parseXml = function (xmlStr) {
            var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
            return xmlDoc;
        };
    } else {
        parseXml = function () { return null; }
    }
```

hop it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want what I think you want (show and hide element **sequentially**), this would be the solution:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#ulId').children().each(
    function(){  
        //access to form element via $(this)
        var html = $(this).html();
        $('#dis').hide(2000, function(){
           $(this).html(html, function(){
              $(this).show(2000)
           });
        })        
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers